# Comparing the source of an Image (If statement)

Tags: javascript

So, I'm trying to create an If statement to compare the source of my Image so I can change it with the corresponding reversed image.

```
function changeBack() {
let image = document.getElementById('product__picture');  
    console.log(image);
if(image.src === 'assets/red.jpg'){
    image.src = ('assets/red-reversed.jpg');
    console.log(image);

} else if(image.src === 'assets/orange.jpg'){
    image.src = ('assets/orange-reversed.jpg');
}
```

HTML:

```
<article class="product">
       <h2 class="hidden">Display Picture</h2>
       <img id="product__picture" src="assets/red.jpg" alt="Laptop case">
</article>
```

Here's my onclick button:

```
 <article id="reverse">
        <h2 class="subtitle">Select side</h2>
        <div id="reverse__container">
        <p id="front" class="reverse__text">Front</p>
        <p id="back" class="reverse__text" onclick="changeBack();">Back</p>
    </div>
    </article>
```

Comment: Don't you just need to read from image.src as well as set it? You also don't need the brackets around the strings, but they shouldn't cause problems either.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check `src` property and not the object.

BTW, strings do not need parentheses around.

```
function changeBack() {
    let image = document.getElementById('product__picture');

    if (image.src === 'assets/red.jpg') {
        image.src = 'assets/red-reversed.assets';
    } else if (image.src === 'assets/orange.jpg') {
        image.src = 'assets/orange-reversed.jpg';
    }
}
```

Comment: Be advised that the `image.src` can be the full url and not only 'assets/red.jpg'

Comment: @LucasOliveira I checked by putting it into a console.log() and it says 'assets/red.jpg' so that should be fine?

Comment: Ok!! No problem then... The solution above is correct :)

Answer (score 0):

compare the src property of the images and not the image Objects themselves!
You also do not need the extra parentheses around the string properties.
furthermore, please use === instead == for equality comparisons of the same type. I almost never use double equals.

```
function changeBack() {
  let image = document.getElementById('product__picture');  

  if(image.src === 'assets/red.jpg'){
      image.src = 'assets/red-reversed.assets'
  } else if(image.src === 'assets/orange.jpg') {
      image.src = 'assets/orange-reversed.jpg';
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't seem to get in my if statement now, even though my source is correct

Comment: what do you see in the console if you logged `image.src`